# UICollectionViewFlowLayout - How do I get even row and column spacing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

[image: Flow Layout]

[UICollectionViewFlowLayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html) has two properties which state the minimum spacing for rows and columns:

- minimumLineSpacing
- minimumInteritemSpacing

How can I set a constraint where the spacing is equal?  Setting both properties the same dose not do the trick since they are minimums.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue here, of course, is that you are assuming that all items are the same size. That makes the idea of "evenness" pretty easy. But the flow layout does not make that assumption; it works the way it does because it is prepared to layout items of varying sizes.

You say "even" but you do not specify the conditions of evenness. How is this evenness to be attained? You have to consider what, exactly, you are after.

- If you accept that the flow layout is going to space the items out so as to *full justify* them on both sides of the screen, then obviously the flow layout will use a larger horizontal spacing value than your `minimumInteritemSpacing` in order to make that happen. Clearly, in that case, you need a larger `minimumLineSpace` value if you want it to be more like the horizontal spacing that the flow layout is using. Alternatively, increase the `sectionInset` on both sides to *reduce* the horizontal spacing throughout.
- If you do *not* accept that the flow layout is going to space the items out to justify them on both sides, then you can set the horizontal spacing exactly, but then clearly the items will need to be left justified (or centered), not full justified. You can do that by subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout.